# vim python turtle window

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, turtle-graphics

I'm on a Mac with macOS Mojave  v. 10.14.3 .
I'm using vim per professors edict.
I learning python as part of a unix class.
My first lines in vim are:

```
import turtle             # Allows us to use turtles
wn = turtle.Screen()      # Creates a playground for turtles
alex = turtle.Turtle()    # Create a turtle, assign to alex

alex.forward(50)          # Tell alex to move forward by 50 units
alex.left(90)             # Tell alex to turn by 90 degrees
alex.forward(30)          # Complete the second side of a rectangle

wn.mainloop()             # Wait for user to close window
```

These lines are copied from:
How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 3

Doing w | !python % on the command line yields:

the window appears and immediately vanishes!

with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "turtle", line 2, in <module>
    wn = turtle.Screen()      # Creates a playground for turtles
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 3553, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 3569, in __init__
    _Screen._root = self._root = _Root()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 458, in __init__
    TK.Tk.__init__(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1823, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I tried the same thing using ssh to my RPi (what we use for learning about the kernel) and got:

the window appears and immediately disappears; as above.  I didn't copy the shell response; I wanted to try the following.

I then tried logging directly into the RPi with full 'windows' regalia after shutdown and tried the same script and the same command line entry and got:

The same window problem with the addition of what appeared to be drawing on the window before disappearing.  Further:

```
Traceback (most recent call):
   File "turtle", line 9, in <module>
     wn.mainloop()        # wait for user to close window
AttributeError: '_screen' object has no attribute 'mainloop'
```

I hope I'm not too through.
I'll not see the professor for another 2 weeks and possibly longer as I'm to have shoulder surgery.

Comment: The path `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py` indicates the usage of Python 2 for code intended for Python 3. So, try `brew install python` and then in Vim `:w | !python3 %`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this.  I tried using python3 and got the same problem.  I have the python installed by Apple + python 2.7, 3.1, 3.6 and 3.7. I don't know if I can delete any of them without effecting' one of the others.  Through the terminal, I see "ls /Library/Python/2.6" and "ls /Library/Python/2.7".  I think these were installed by Apple.  In "Applications" I have Python 2.7, 3.1, 3.6, 3.7 .  How I got all of them???  Occasionally my daughter asks to use my computer - perchance.  Can I use AppDelete to remove some?  Is the causing my problem?

Comment: I just tried python3 on the RPi and I got a window!!!  I don't know why I only tried 'python3' on the mac.  I did try it through ssh on the RPi.  i.e. Mac ------> ssh -----RPi.  Thank you profusely!!!  I should have tried more....

Answer (score 1):

Even today, Apple's Mac OS X by default supplies multiple versions of Python 2 (invoked as `python` at the command line) and no versions of Python 3.  You should install your own Python 3 (typically invoked as `python3` at the command line.)

You can also make code this basic insensitive to the difference:

```
import turtle  # Allows us to use turtles

wn = turtle.Screen()  # Creates a playground for turtles
alex = turtle.Turtle()  # Create a turtle, assign to alex

alex.forward(50)  # Tell alex to move forward by 50 units
alex.left(90)  # Tell alex to turn by 90 degrees
alex.forward(30)  # Complete the second side of a rectangle

wn.exitonclick()  # Wait for user to close (or click on) window
```

The above should run the same on either major version of Python.